# Parallellogram in Hyperbolic Geometry is not composed of two congruent triangles.

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I am trying to show that in hyperbolic geometry, any diagonal of a parallellogram $\square ABCD$ divides the parallellogram into two **non**-congruent triangles.

I have tried assuming the contrary, and used that the summit of a Saccheri quadrilateral is longer than the base, and that the in a Lambert quadrialteral, the length of a side is less than that of the opposite side, but I have not been able to derive a contradiction despite many efforts. Another possibility would be to construct a triangle based on this having angle sum $\geq 180$, or showing that some linear pair of angles violate the Linear Pair Theorem.

Can anyone give me a **hint** on how to approach this problem?

I have been able to show that it cannot be true for every parallellogram $\square ABCD$, that is; I have been able to show that there exists a parallellogram $\square ABCD$ having a diagonal that divides it into noncongruent triangles. I did that as follows:

Let $l=\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, and let $E \neq A$ be a point of intersection between $l$ and some line $m$ through $D$ parallell to $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ (so $m \neq \overleftrightarrow{AD}$). Then $\square EBCD$ is also a parallellogram. If the the diagonals of this parallellogram divides it into congruent triangles, then $EB=DC=AB$, giving the contradiction $EA=0$.

But this does not prove that the statement is true for **every** parallellogram....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, take a parallelogram which is a regular quadrilateral.

Comment: Nice. How did I not see that...?  We can relax this to equilateral parallellogram since we don't need the pairs of opposite angles to be congruent (I suspect this is what you meant though). Do you know wheter or not these exhaust the counterexamples to this statement?

Comment: Probably one could use symmetry arguments to work out all the cases. That would be another question, though.